# Disabling the AxWebbrowser Context Menu VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, contextmenu, axwebbrowser

I'm using Axwebbrowser to display HTML page in my VB.NET application and i would like to know how disable its context menu ?

I use AxWebbrowser more than the original Webbrowser component because it handle the NewWindows 2 event that help me getting the popup url when a link is open in a new tab for example.

So i can't use the Webbrowser1.ContextMenuEnabled = False

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I've fixed the problem with an extended webbrowser version ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to trap the WM_RBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK messages at the application level.  You can add a message filter to your application using the statement `Application.AddMessageFilter(instance of IMessageFilter)`.  In the example below, the [ImessageFilter interferace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) is implemented by the form containing the AXWebrowser control.  As the filter is application wide, it is added/removed when the form activates/deactivates.

```
Public Class Form1
    Implements IMessageFilter

    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN  As Int32 = &H204
        Const WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK As Int32 = &H206
        ' check that the message is WM_RBUTTONDOWN Or WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK
        ' verify AxWebBrowser1 is not null
        ' verify the target is AxWebBrowser1
        Return (m.Msg = WM_RBUTTONDOWN OrElse m.Msg = WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK) AndAlso (AxWebBrowser1 IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (AxWebBrowser1 Is Control.FromChildHandle(m.HWnd))
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnActivated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnActivated(e)
        ' Filter is application wide, activate filter with form
        Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDeactivate(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDeactivate(e)
        ' Filter is application wide, remove when form not active
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo in `Const  As Int32 = &H204`. The return might be easier to read if it was broken down in a `Select Case True` block, but that may just be a style preference on my part.

Comment: @MrGadget, Thank you for pointing that out.  I must have done a cut instead of copy of WM_RBUTTONDOWN while I composing the explanation/